# Equal height items in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, height

I want that all elements in a list be equal height. For this, I am using the [jquery.matchHeigh](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) plugin. However, the selected items are not being updated automatically

when resize the screen:

[image]

I would like the sizes to be updated automatically, but I only get this result when updating the

page:

[image]

I am using the basic function:

```
$('.product-info .product-name').matchHeight({ property: 'min-height' });
```

The complete code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5x1pnwyg/7/).

I'm using [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) for list.

Comment: You could put your `matchHeight();` function within a `$(window).on("resize", function() { //here } )` event, though depending on how the `matchHeight` works, this could be a performance nightmare. Why not just use CSS?

Comment: @Santi The plugin listens for those events. The demo you provided works as intended.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Not for me it doesn't. As soon as I compress the window, the items all become misaligned. However, when I [put it in a listener](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/5x1pnwyg/8/) it works just fine. **EDIT:** Correction, the included example seems to have a slight lag-time upon releasing the window, however it *does* seem to align them eventually.

Comment: @Santi Thanks! I tested here and the problem seems to continue: http://imgur.com/a/znXuf

Comment: *How* are you resizing the window? @IvankaTodorova I now notice that if you double click the window header instead of dragging the window size, both OP's example and my own do not work.

Comment: @Brightweb Major work-around but you could try [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/5x1pnwyg/10/).

Comment: @Santi I'm dragging the mouse from right to left. And if we were to just use .css, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: I mean it depends on how you're populating things, as it may be quite a bit of work to turn back. However there are a few ways listed [here](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).

Comment: @Santi Your last suggestion worked! :) However, now the script will only have effect when resizing the screen, right? The ideal would be to work for both situations (with and without resizing).

Comment: I'll post it as an answer and include something to remedy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here just seems to be a matter of lag-time between a window resize and the actual `window.resize` event firing. By wrapping the event in a window resize and adding a slight timeout, I've manage to remedy the issue:

```
var lagTime = 500;   //Play around with this number
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.product-info .product-name').matchHeight({
        property: 'min-height'
    })}
    , lagTime);
}).trigger("resize");
```

Notice I've also included a `.trigger()` on the end of it, which will fire the `resize` event once when the page loads.

---

Consider reducing the `lagTime` variable as needed, you should be able to get away with something lower than the `500` that I'm using in this example.

Comment: Thank you! I read the plugin documentation again and found the following article: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height/issues/60#issuecomment-155913995. Combining with your answer, I believe I arrived at the expected result. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/5x1pnwyg/15/

Answer (score 1):

Is using flexbox in your CSS an option? If so, add `display: flex;` to the parent and all child element heights will be equal. You will need to play with which child elements nested inside need `position: absolute;` etc. but this can be done with CSS without modifying the HTML markup.

I have a more simplified codepen demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjyVyZ

Answer (score 1):

I read the  [jquery.matchHeigh plugin documentation](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) again and found this [article](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height/issues/60#issuecomment-155913995). Combining with the answer from [Santi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026606/santi), I believe I arrived at the expected result:

```
// the original group of .product-info .product-name
$('.product-info .product-name').matchHeight({ property: 'min-height' });

// on rezise event
$(window).on("resize", function() {

  setTimeout(function() {

  // remove the old group
  $('.product-info .product-name').matchHeight({ remove: true });

  // apply matchHeight on the new selection, which includes the new element
  $('.product-info .product-name').matchHeight();

  }, 250);

})
```

Check out the final code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5x1pnwyg/15/). Thank you all!